# How to read subpages on server?

Tags: php, web

Can I get a list of files on any page?
For example on page

> *www.90minut.pl/*

Every news on page is in folder "news" eg.

> *www.90minut.pl/news/238/news2387307-Deniz-Yilmaz-nie-zagra-z-Legia.html*

I would like to see all files on

> *www.90minut.pl/**news/***

Is it possible in PHP?

Comment: Are you asking about guessing what URLs a server will return a `200 OK` response for? Or reading the file system of the server that your program is running on? What does ftp have to do with this?

Comment: I would like to read for eg. all files on "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/" Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

Unless the site provides you with links, there is no way to tell what resources it is hosting.

Answer (score 0):

of course you can, but, you have to pay attention if the structure from the website/system is using structure like MVC or it's using friendly urls, and the server's permission it's setted as read mode or read/write.

Comment: Man, i was reading carefully what you want, and now i'm understanding about your question...so, lets go.
The only way to get these files is using ssh or ftp functions, otherwise, it's impossible. if you have been the owner of website and has the source code you can write a script to read the files.